# spring-boot mongodb 4.0 compatibility

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Which version of `spring-boot` is compatible with `MongoDB 4.0`?

Is there an advisable way to use `spring-boot 2.0.5 RELEASE` with `MongoDB 4.0`?

Or better to use `spring boot 2.0.5` which has mongo driver version `3.6.x` with MongoDB 3.6`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not strictly needed to have the latest driver and spring data mongo in order to use a mongodb 4.0; However in the [spring data changelog](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/changelog.txt) you can see the various changes regarding the driver and DB update, there you can see that in version `2.1.0.RC1` they started adding support for version 4.0 of the database as well as in version `1.10.15.RELEASE`. Latest GA version [2.1.0.RELEASE documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) has updated to `MongoDB Java Driver 3.8.2`.

The java driver and Spring will always be a bit behind with new functionalities introduced by each version of MongoDB. So my suggestion if you are starting now is to use the latest `2.1.0.RELEASE` (https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/#quick-start)

Edit:

- How Mongo was before version 4.0 [how-acid-mongodb](https://dzone.com/articles/how-acid-mongodb)
- ACID in mongo 4.0 [multi document transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb)
- Spring data mongo support for [transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.transactions)

Comment: Since I'm using `spring-boot`, in that case, I'd have to override the `spring-boot-mongodb` driver version **alone**, which in general is not advised? 

Can I assume, if I do not use the **new** features of MongoDB 4.0 like _Transaction Support (ACID)_ and use the `spring-data-mongodb' for compatible features of `3.6.0`, is that going to advisable?

Comment: I would always avoid to change spring dependencies unless really needed. You can safely use spring data mongo as is, why not? If you want to make use of the new features such as transaction https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.transactions you have it availbable, there is no need to update the driver by hand.

Comment: If you find the answer incomplete/wrong/inaccurate please let me know, a negative vote without pointing why make it difficult to improve the answer when needed

Comment: No down votes from my side. The latest version of `spring-boot` doesn't use the latest `MongoDB 4.0` compatible `spring-data-mongo` version and hence the confusion.